# For new package downloading

Tags: ros, tutorials, rosinstall, package, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

May I ask a fresh question, that when i try to run find_object package,it does not be downloaded. And reference is "http://www.ros.org/wiki/find_object/Tutorials/Running%20the%20basic%20find%20object%20demo"
I ask some of my colleagues that it only should download one by one files at "https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_cturtle/stacks/find_object/",.
which is so confused to me, cause it has too many files and sub-files.

So could there be anther way to download this SVN source quickly?

Best regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9197/for-new-package-downloading/) by [Yongqiang Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/162/yongqiang-gao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2011-02-24

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yongqiang Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/162/yongqiang-gao/) on 2011-02-24**:
OK, we can solve problem when we face it. Thank u. and best regards.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-02-24**:
This question applies to many use cases, in addition to that specific tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That tutorial skips over several important preliminary steps. This is the best answer I know. Maybe someone else has a better approach.

Install the ROS binary packages if you have not already (see: [Ubuntu C-turtle installation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cturtle/Installation/Ubuntu)).

Create your own rosinstall file (`find_object.rosinstall` for this example), containing these three lines:

```
- other: {local-name: /opt/ros/cturtle/ros}
- other: {local-name: /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks}
- svn: {local-name: find_object, uri: 'https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_cturtle/stacks/find_object'}
```

Run [rosinstall](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall) on that file, and source the `setup.bash` script (which you should probably add to your `~/.bashrc` script).

You can do all of the above with these shell commands:

```
$ cp /opt/ros/cturtle/.rosinstall find_object.rosinstall
$ roslocate info find_object >> find_object.rosinstall
$ rosinstall ~/ros find_object.rosinstall
$ source ~/ros/setup.bash
```

Follow the tutorial after that.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on 2013-05-12**:
how do you create the rosinstall file? do you just create with a text editor and place it in the /opt/ros/cturtle/ directory?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-13**:
C-turtle was a long time ago. You probably want to run a more recent ROS distro. Each distro comes with a .rosinstall in its top-level directory.